# Newton's method of roots?

Tags: calculus

Find the $x_1$ and $x_2$ approximations from Newton's method when finding the real roots of $x^3−5 = 0$ starting with $x_0 =1$.

What does this even mean? I looked it up on Google and it says $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Am I supposed to place the $x^3−5$ quote into the formula? What next?

Comment: $f(x) = x^3-5$, now write the iteration formula. Maybe read: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/NewtonsMethod.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^3−5$. Then $f'(x) = 3x^2$. So Newton's method becomes $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^3−5}{3x_n^2}$$

Start with $n=0$ so $x_n = x_0 =1$. Use $x_0$ calculate $x_1$. Then use Newton's formula again with $x_n = x_1$ to calculate $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary Kibble showed, $x_{n+1}= x_n- \frac{x_n^3- 5}{3x_n^2}$.  Notice that this is the same as $x_{n+1}= x_n- \frac{1}{3}x_n+ \frac{5}{3x_n^2}= \frac{2}{3}x_n+ \frac{5}{3x_n^2}$.  It might be easier to calculate that way.  With the initial value $x_0= 1$, that formula gives $x_1=\frac{2}{3}(1)+ \frac{5}{3(1^2)}= \frac{2}{3}+ \frac{5}{3}= \frac{7}{3}$.  Then $x_2= \frac{2}{3}\frac{7}{3}+ \frac{5}{3(\frac{7}{3})}= \frac{14}{9}+ \frac{5}{7}= \frac{98+ 45}{63}= \frac{143}{63}$ etc.

Comment: Maybe $(7/3)^2$ should be in the denominator of the second term for $x_2$?